# Pivot table using Connection to External Workbook - #DIV/0! Error when averaging

Tags: excel, pivot-table

My goal is to keep a workbook with several sheets, each of which would have a pivot table and chart linked to an external workbook. The thought is to have all my charts for reporting purposes in one place instead of spread across the various sheets. The problem I'm having is when I create a connection to the other workbook (Data>Connections>Connections) and build out the Pivot table, only 1 of the columns I'm attempting to average actually returns the correct values. All other columns I attempt to average return a #DIV/0! error. The weird thing is when I build the pivot table in the workbook where the data actually resides everything works fine. Other posts show how to deal with making the pivot table display '0' or some other such thing instead of the error name, but that isn't the issue. The values returned should not be 0. Recreated this on separate machines all having the same issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That error results in you trying to divide something with zero? An average is a division. Have you checked your data?

Comment: Data is fine. Pivot table works as it should when it is housed in the workbook where the data is and from another open workbook referencing the data. The issue seems to be with the external connection.